# Filter WooCommerce products with post__in and additional meta queries

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to find products that are on sale (including product variations) in addition to another meta_query of price under X.

The `wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()` function will return the IDs of products (including variations) that are on sale. Therefore I added this to `post__in`.

`$query_args['post__in'] = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();`

However, this will override my second part of the query which is to find products under £X

```
$query_args = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'price' => array(
        'key' => '_price',
        'value' => 15,
        'compare' => '<',
        'type' => 'numeric'
    ),
    'stock_status' => array(
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'instock',
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
);

return $query_args;
```

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
    'post__not_in' => array( $product_id ),
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'return' => 'ids',
    'post__in' => wc_get_product_ids_on_sale(),
    'meta_query' => $meta_query; // this contains the price under X query
);
```

I believe `post__in` is telling WP_Query to only return those posts regardless of any other query.

Are there appropriate methods to do these queries separately and combine them in some way?

Answer (score 0):

```
$on_sale_product_ids = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();

$queried_products = wc_get_products(array(
    'limit' => 1000,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'price_and_stock' => true,
));
$on_sale_products = wc_get_products(array('include' => array_values($on_sale_product_ids) , 'limit' => count($on_sale_product_ids)) );

$total_products = array_merge($on_sale_products,$queried_products );
```

Add below code snippet for price_and_stock combination query.

```
function handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['price_and_stock'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] =    array( 'relation' => 'AND',
    'price' => array(
        'key' => '_price',
        'value' => 9,
        'compare' => '<',
        'type' => 'numeric'
    ),
    'stock_status' => array(
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'instock',
        'compare' => '=',
    )
            );
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
```

More details on the custom query can be [found here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

**== Alternate ==**

Note: you cannot combine `post__in` and `post__not_in` in the same query. `post__in` and `post__not_in` are mutually exclusive.

```
$meta_query = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                'price' => array(
                    'key' => '_price',
                    'value' => 9,
                    'compare' => '<',
                    'type' => 'numeric'
                ),
                'stock_status' => array(
                    'key' => '_stock_status',
                    'value' => 'instock',
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            );
        
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
                'posts_per_page' => 1000,
                'return' => 'ids',
                'post__in' => wc_get_product_ids_on_sale(),
                'meta_query' => $meta_query // this contains the price under X query
            );
            $total_products = wc_get_products($args);
```

Comment: Thanks @mujuonly, I'll test your approaches later. I don't see any difference from my approach to your alternative approach.

Comment: @wharfdale Removed `post_not_in` from your approach as `post__in` and `post__not_in` are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Conflict does not happen because of the combination of `meta_query` and `post__in`, it happens because `post__not_in` and `post__in` can't work in the same query. Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

If you wish to search through products on sale together with excluding one product in the same query, you can try `array_diff` them together and add them to `post__in` only.

Example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'return' => 'ids',
    'post__in' => array_diff(wc_get_product_ids_on_sale(), [ $product_id ]),
    'meta_query' => $meta_query; // this contains the price under X query
);
```

This way your are telling your query to search through products that are on sale, excluding the one with `$product_id`.
Just make sure your `wc_` function always returns an array or else this could fail.